# DHCP and network switches

Tags: networking

When a DHCP server assigns IP addresses to devices, do network switches pass along assigned addresses from the DHCP server to the device requesting an address, or does the switch use it's assigned IP address for all connected devices?

Comment: You can think of a switch as a power strip. https://i.imgur.com/CF4Vo.jpg

Comment: @sickest I'd suggest its more like a mains board (some control, but does not modify the voltage or frequency provided to the power point) - a power strip is more analogous to a hub!

Comment: lol I'm trying to make a simple analogy. Your analogy is more complex than explaining what a switch ACTUALLY does. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more correct to say the switch passes along the assigned addresses.

In reality the (typical) switch has no concept of an IP address, it uses MAC addresses to communicate between devices. In fact, DHCP is primarily mapping the MAC address associated with hardware and switching fabric with an IP address associated with Internet. (it does other things as well, like hand out DNS and gateway, but the core database it manages is one of MAC -> IP assignment)

Comment: Its also worth noting that most (ie unmanaged/dumb) switches dont have an IP or MAC address associated with them. Managed switches require MAC addresses so they can communicate with the configuring client and be configured - ie its because things like a web interface require an IP address assignef to the switch which in turn requires a MAC address as its a requirement of communicating with a device on an ethernet network.